# Trying to create a pdf in different languages in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, fonts

I want to print Hindi language in my PDF, I've also tried using Raleway-Regular.ttf font by Google but it also didn't worked.

```
final font = await rootBundle.load("fonts/ARIAL.TTF");
final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(font);

pdf.addPage(
  pw.MultiPage(
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(32),
    build: (pw.Context context){
    return <pw.Widget>[
      pw.Center(
        child: pw.Text("मेन",style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 16,font: ttf))
      ),
      pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
      pw.Center(
      child: pw.Text("ABC",style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 16))
    ),
  ),
),
```

I'm getting following Error:

***I/flutter (24862): Cannot decode the string to Latin1.
I/flutter (24862): This font does not support Unicode characters.
I/flutter (24862): If you want to use strings other than Latin strings, use a TrueType (TTF) font instead.
I/flutter (24862): See https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/wiki/Fonts-Management
I/flutter (24862): ---------------------------------------------
E/flutter (24862): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (string): Contains invalid characters.: "मेन"

---

Comment: I've got a hunch that ARIAL doesn't support anything other than latin1, and hindi cannot be represented in that.  You'll need a fuller font.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am also facing the same error its because the fonts you are using does not support that language , if you want to use hindi language then you can use hind-regular.ttl font it supports both the fonts hindi and english.

here is the example what i got.

// step 1- add font locatin in pubspec

fonts:
- family: hind
fonts:
- asset: assets/hind.ttf

//step 2-

final pdf = pw.Document();

```
final font = await rootBundle.load("assets/hind.ttf");

final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(font);
```

then just apply this ttf in the fontStyle

packages i m using -

import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

universal_html: ^1.2.3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVsqL.png)
pdf: ^1.11.1

Comment: hey can you please share link of the fonts zip i am unable to find

Answer (score 1):

#### **For printing Bangla font use this method:**

1. Use font *[SiyamRupaliANSI](https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/Siyam%20Rupali%20ANSI.ttf)*
2. Use the bangla font and convert it to [UNICODE TO BIJOY](https://bsbk.portal.gov.bd/apps/bangla-converter/index.html?)
   [image]
3. Copy the converted code and paste it to your Text widget with fontfamily ***SiyamRupaliANSI***
   **CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
final font = await rootBundle.load("fonts/SiyamRupaliANSI.ttf");
pw.Text( "e‡Kqv", style: pw.TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            font: Font.ttf(font),
                    ),
```

4. And get this final output of pdf

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some issues are there with Unicode translations . Please take care of it https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/198

You can use syncfusion pdf library (You need to buy subscription). You will get all kind of support including search,rtl, unicode support .

```
final  font = await rootBundle.load("assets/fonts/hind.ttf");
final  ttf = Font.ttf(font);
final pdf = pw.Document();
pw.Text(
  'Your text',
  textDirection:TextDirection.rtl, // If you need in opp direction like urdu
  style: pw.TextStyle(
  font: ttf,))
```

Comment: hey can you please share link of the fonts zip i am unable to find

Answer (score 0):

If someone still has this problem

```
 final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/fonts/opensans_regular.ttf');

 final  dataint = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes,data.lengthInBytes);

 final  PdfFont  font  =  PdfTrueTypeFont (date,12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the language not works well with the flutter pdf plugin

In Tamil language, I face problems when two characters merge.

so, i modified the tff with available tools and replaced that character with that character.
as the result, i can able to get the output

```
String path = 'assets/custom_Anand_MuktaMalar.ttf';
pw.Font? tamilFont = pw.Font.ttf(await rootBundle.load(path));
pw.Text('உவவுமதி உருவின் ஓங்கல் வெண்குடை'.toPrintPdf)

pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
        theme: pw.ThemeData(defaultTextStyle: pw.TextStyle(font: tamilFont)),
  ));
```

for further ref, you can see my project:
https://github.com/anandsubbu007/anand-work/tree/BLOC/tamil_pdf

[image]

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Also, you need to include more information in an answer than just a link, it needs to show how to solve the user's problem. Also, the question is asking about Hindi, not Tamil, so I don't see how your answer is relevant. Also, the issue in the repo that you've linked to is already linked in another https://stackoverflow.com/a/67470651 so this answer is not adding anything of value.