# Malayalam font is not rendering when creating pdf in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, pdf

I am using Malayalam custom font in my flutter project and it is rendering in android and iOS is fine. But when we try to create a pdf it will not showing the Malayalam content and showing the corresponding English characters

await Printing.convertHtml( html:content ).then((value) { bytes1=value; // showLoader(); Navigator.push( NavigationService.navigationKey.currentContext!, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PdfViewer(doc: value), )); }); [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzaa7.png

By this way only I can share the html content. It is good when we use English language but in the case where we use malayalam or any other language, the pdf is not rendering well. But the weird point is that , when we try to render the pdf in iOS simulator (iPhone 13) it is rendering perfectly. The issues exist only in android devices

Comment: Please try to help me , it will be greatful

Comment: Are you using any  package to  create PDF? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66719354/10157127) might help you

Comment: I am using pdf: ^3.7.1 library

Comment: I am getting the html data from the backend and it is rendering on app, while using the Syncfusion library , it will not create the html output in pdf file

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65640742/10157127)

Comment: You can include all this information on question so that others can easily focus eon specific issue, Also try including [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is anyone have the solution?

Comment: Please help me if anyone knows

Comment: Try including sample widget that will reproduce this issue. Then we might be able to help. Also you can create git issue

Comment: I have added the code snippet  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzaa7.png @YeasinSheikh

Comment: seems like I cant help with it, you can try creating git issue

Comment: You can try this trick for now https://stackoverflow.com/a/73098121/12379401